# How to access array/object inside function in javascript ?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I have array outside function like below :

```
var daily = [];
daily["data"]=[];
daily["data"].push('hello');

function demo()
{
console.log(daily); // not working here
}
```

How to declare this object as global in Javascript ?

Comment: Use `{}` for objects. `[]` are used for arrays. But then you can't use `push` so you need to make up your mind what type of structure you're using.

Comment: ok but push is not working in object

Comment: @Andy This is wild: http://jsfiddle.net/2NSUQ/. Take a look at the console output...at least tested in Chrome. Seems to be an associative array...

Comment: @crush, [see my amendment](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/2NSUQ/2/). If you try to find the length it returns `0`. See also: http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/

Comment: @Andy I guess I just forgot that JavaScript arrays actually have the ability to use a string value as an index. It's probably been a decade since I attempted that, if ever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because your function is being hoisted. Try this instead for your function.

```
var demo = function(){
  console.log(daily);
}
```

You might also considering just passing that daily variable into  your function like so,

```
var demo = function(d){
  console.log(d);
}
```

then when  you want to call it.

```
demo(daily);
```

Comment: how do i call this function ?

Comment: Same as you normally would. demo(); Also if I were you consider passing in daily into the function, var demo = function(d){console.log(d)} then when you call it demo(daily);